# How do you profile a Python script from Windows command line using PyPy and vmprof?

Tags: python, command-line, profiling, pypy

I have a Python script that I want to profile using vmprof to figure out what parts of the code are slow. Since PyPy is generally faster, I also want to profile the script while it is using the PyPy JIT. If the script is named myscript.py, how do you structure the command on the command line to do this?

I have already installed vmprof using

> pip install vmprof

Answer (score 0):

I would be suprised if it works, but the command is `pypy -m vmprof myscript.py <your program args>`. I would expect it to crash saying vmprof is not supported on windows.